# Updating the column values in one table based on values in other tables-Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, multiple-columns

My question is critical and I have three tables as below...

Investor Table:

```
Investor_ID Total_amt_Invested Current_Value
ABC             100
```

Investment_info table:

```
Investor_ID    Entity_ID  No_of_units_bought
ABC             XYZ1       400
ABC             XYZ2       600
ABC             XYZ3      1000
```

Entity_info table:

```
Entity_ID   Listed_NPV current_NPV
XYZ1        .05           1
XYZ2        .05           2
XYZ3        .05           3
```

In the above table the current_value in Investor table should be automatically calculated as 400*1+600*2+3*1000.......how can I update the column info? Any suggestions, please.

Comment: Looks pretty basic why don't you show some effort to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Some fancy example with autocompliting your column

```
-- create base tables
CREATE TABLE investor
  (investor_id        VARCHAR2(30),
   total_amt_invested INTEGER,
   current_value      INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE investment_info
  (investor_id        VARCHAR2(30),
   entity_id          VARCHAR2(30),
   no_of_units_bought INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE entity_info
  (entity_id   VARCHAR2(30),
   listed_npv  NUMBER,
   current_npv INTEGER);

-- insert data   
insert into investor values ('ABC', 100, null);
insert into investment_info values ('ABC', 'XYZ1', 400); 
insert into investment_info values ('ABC', 'XYZ2', 600); 
insert into investment_info values ('ABC', 'XYZ3', 1000); 
insert into entity_info values ('XYZ1', .05, 1); 
insert into entity_info values ('XYZ2', .05, 2); 
insert into entity_info values ('XYZ3', .05, 3); 
insert into investor values ('BCD', 100, null); 
insert into investment_info values ('BCD', 'XYZ4', 350); 
insert into entity_info values ('XYZ4', .05, 4);
commit;

-- create function to return total invest amount   
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_total_invest(p_investor_id VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
DETERMINISTIC
RESULT_CACHE 
-- you don't need RELIES_ON if version 11.2+
RELIES_ON (investment_info, entity_info)
IS
  l_result   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT sum(no_of_units_bought * current_npv)
    INTO l_result
    FROM investment_info 
         JOIN entity_info
         ON investment_info.entity_id = entity_info.entity_id      
   WHERE investor_id = p_investor_id;
   RETURN l_result;
END;
/

-- alter table to add autocalculated virtual column
ALTER TABLE investor ADD (auto_current_value GENERATED ALWAYS AS (get_total_invest(investor_id)));

-- recreate function without DETERMINISTIC (read documantion about virtual column)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_total_invest(p_investor_id VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
RESULT_CACHE
-- you don't need RELIES_ON if version 11.2+
RELIES_ON (investment_info, entity_info)
IS
  l_result   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT sum(no_of_units_bought * current_npv)
    INTO l_result
    FROM investment_info 
         JOIN entity_info
         ON investment_info.entity_id = entity_info.entity_id      
   WHERE investor_id = p_investor_id;
  RETURN l_result;
END;
/

SELECT *
  FROM investor;

insert into investment_info values ('ABC', 'XYZ3', 1100); 
COMMIT;

SELECT *
  FROM investor;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will Calculate `Current Value` for each `Investor_ID`

```
select inv.Investor_ID ,
       sum(inv_info.No_of_units_bought*ent_info.current_NPV) as Current_Value    
from Investor inv 
inner join Investment_info inv_info on inv.Investor_ID=inv_info.Investor_ID 
inner join Entity_info ent_info on inv_info.Entity_ID=ent_info.Entity_ID
group by inv.Investor_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update statement you are looking for:

```
update investor inv set current_value = (select
sum(i.no_of_units_bought * e.current_npv) 
from investment_info i join entity_info e
on i.entity_id = e.entity_id
where inv.investor_id = i.investor_id
group by i.investor_id);
```

Here are the steps followed:

- Create tables

> ```
> create table investor (investor_id vachar2(30), total_amt_invested integer, current_value integer);
> create table investment_info (investor_id varchar2(30), entity_id varchar2(30), no_of_units_bought integer);
> create table entity_info (entity_id varchar2(30), listed_npv number, current_npv integer);
> ```

- Insert data

> ```
> insert into investor values ('ABC', 100, null);
> insert into investment_info values ('ABC', 'XYZ1', 400); 
> insert into investment_info values ('ABC', 'XYZ2', 600); 
> insert into investment_info values ('ABC', 'XYZ3', 1000); 
> insert into entity_info values ('XYZ1', .05, 1); 
> insert into entity_info values ('XYZ2', .05, 2); 
> insert into entity_info values ('XYZ3', .05, 3); 
> insert into investor values ('BCD', 100, null); 
> insert into investment_info values ('BCD', 'XYZ4', 350); 
> insert into entity_info values ('XYZ4', .05, 4);
> ```

- Run the above update statement to update investor and validate

> ```
> SQL> select * from investor;
>
> INVESTOR_ID              TOTAL_AMT_INVESTED CURRENT_VALUE
> ------------------------------ ------------------ -------------
> ABC                         100      4600
> BCD                         100      1400
> ```